# Sorting order of subsequent rows after deleting a row datatables

Tags: php, sorting, datatables

We're using datatables that is getting populated from the PHP source. Table contains one integer column for ordering of the records. On deleting a row, I want the order column of the subsequent rows to be updated automatically in the database as it is coming from the server side. So for example If I delete a row with order = 2, then the subsequent rows order should be automatically updated i.e order 3 should become 2, 4 become 3 and so on. But this is an overhead If I've a million of records and I delete a 100th row and then all the order of the subsequent rows have to be updated upto million. 
So is there a workaround for this overhead to be minimized ?

Thanks

Comment: I will not do that, I will just use a count variable in `foreach loop` to represent the data in serial order to front users.

Comment: What if you set the order of the deleted row to the `max(order) + 1` and then order your data `ASC`.

Comment: @Hirumina Currently I'm doing the same thing i.e `max(order) + 1` for the insertion of new records. But as I said It's when I delete the records what would be the effective way to update the subsequent row orders.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal this is what isn't required actually.

Comment: I'm sure that you are not hard deleting your data.So that, you must have a flag to identify if the record is deleted or not.In that case you have to use a `update` query to update the flag ex: `flag_is_deleted` to 1 , right. What i'm saying is when you are executing the update query you can update the `order_no` of the particular  deleted record to  `max(order) + 1`

Comment: *ALWAYS make sure that you are not hard deleting any record in you database.maintain a flag for actions like deleting*

Comment: @Hirumina what're you telling to him, He asked for solution of the **subsequent rows**.

Comment: @Hirumina before deleting I update all the orders by iterating eachone using `foreach` loop. It's good for small number of rows but If I've million rows than this approach isn't going to be effective.

Comment: @SohaibAhmad are you using a framework?

Comment: @JairusMartin Yes Phalcon framework

Comment: @SohaibAhmad see https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/pagination, if you combine this with models you don't need to do anything. See also https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/db-models. You should also attempt to post some code.